# How do you introspect web.xml from a servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, web.xml, servlet-filters

Is there a way for a servlet filter to get a list of all servlets and their mappings?

Comment: Not using the standard API. Specific containers might let you do it, but that will depend on your container.

Comment: Its strange that there used to be APIs for things like this, but were dropped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standard API (anymore; and what was there was rather limited) - but it's an XML file with a standard schema. You can obtain it in your filter via:

```
filterConfig.getServletContext().getResource("/WEB-INF/web.xml");
```

and get what you want from it using SAX / DOM / XPath / what have you, e.g.

```
 InputStream is = filterConfig.getServletContext()
   .getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/web.xml");
 DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
   .newDocumentBuilder();
 Document document = builder.parse(is);
 NodeList servlets = document.getElementsByTagName("servlet");
```

Comment: This falls down a bit in EE6, where servlets can be defined by annotations, and by web-fragment.xml files. The same approach can be used on those, though; it's merely a simple matter of programming.